# Free Webflow-like site creator

Tags: gratis, web-development

I am trying to create a site, and I was looking for a fully custom site creator. After some searching and recommendations, I found Webflow.

Unfortunately, [Webflow](https://webflow.com/), although it's exactly what I was looking for in terms of site editor, has certain limitations on its free edition.

So, what I am looking for is a graphical site editor with the functionality of the editor of Webflow. I am not interested in hosting, so it might as well be a normal offline software. In the end, I want to be able to create an html page exactly how I want it, and then add to it the backend functionality I wish.

Side Note: I aim for creating a web app using Meteor, and the said editor will be used to create a front-end looks-based prototype, which will then be used as the base for the app. If this approach is wrong, you may point it out.

Comment: That's https://webflow.com/ for anyone who wants to see what the OP is referring to

Comment: "Webflow ... has certain limitations on its free edition" - you might want to add the [tag:gratis] tag then

Comment: And explain what those limitations are. If we don't know which features you want, how can we help you?

Comment: There are a ton of possible answers, if you would reply to my previous comments. As a general rule, the more detailed requirements that you give to us, the more detailed help that we will be able to give to you.

Comment: I could say the main limitation is that Webflow does not allow you to export the html and css you create with its graphical tool in its free edition. The main point of the question was about a tool that lets you create a site - html and css -  mainly with graphical tools and then lets you fine tune the result and add the desired functionality and business logic with whatever Javascript framework you wish. I made this question two years ago and I have no use of it any more as the project in question was abandoned eventually soon after I posted it. Any generally helpful answers welcome.

Comment: Since the functionality of Webflow seems extremely useful, I guess there should be also desktop tools to accomplish the same job. But my search mainly stumbled across CMS which were not at all what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://macaw.co/ or http://stackhive.com (still not free, though).

Comment: Can you tell us how this answers the OPs question?

Comment: @ Mawg both are graphical site editors with the functionality of Webflow.

Comment: The OP's only objection seems to be that it is not free, which neither of these are. I would be interested in such a free thing myself, so hope that someone will post one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying [Wix Code](https://www.wix.com/code/home)?

It will create a full IDE like inside your site, with real back-end part, API integrations and etc. Really powerful.