# Gratis drag & drop web page designer which generates only one HTML and one CSS file

Tags: windows, gratis, css, html-editor, rad

I am lousy at page layout.

I am looking for a gratis drag & drop web page designer which allows me to drag & drop buttons, checkboxes, lists, text input fields, etc, and to position them.

A form designer will do for me, but I don't object if it handles more.

I want to take its output and add AngularJs code to it. To that end, the output should not be lots & lots of files in lots & lots of directories.

I *prefer* a solution which generates only one HTML and one CSS file (but would accept a small handful).

Basically, I am looking for something to do the layout of the HTML, leaving the coding up to me.

- HTML5
- gratis
- Windows
- all standard HTML form fields
- HTML tables nice to have

Note that I only want the HTML layout. The answer does not even have to be aware of AngularJs. Something like the tools that [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23400/free-webflow-like-site-creator) is asking for.

Comment: related, but not not restricted to a single page, is [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46981/visual-html-5-editor-and-development-tool)

Comment: Hmm, like some [Free online tool](https://html-online.com/editor/)?

Comment: I don't see how to add form fields, nor how to download :-(

Answer (score 1):

I know of two free WYSIWYG web page builders. BlueGriffon and Kompozer. Neither is exactly what you are looking for but are close. They do almost all the programming, you just put links, images, tables wherever you want. Both codes generate single HTML files which you can then edit. There are very helpful tutorials for both by the same author.